# cannot connect an SSL secured database to typeorm

Tags: postgresql, ssl, nestjs, typeorm

This is my first time using NestJS and I am having trouble connecting my Postgres database which is hosted on Digitalocean to NestJS.

I searched online for solutions and tried adding `"ssl": "true" or "extra": { "ssl": "true" }`

Heres my ormconfig.json

```
{
  "type": "postgres",
  "host": "host",
  "port": "port",
  "username": "username",
  "password": "password",
  "database": "database",
  "extra": {
    "ssl": "true"
  },
  "synchronize": "true",
  "logging": "true",
  "entities": ["src/**/*.entity.ts", "dist/**/*.entity.js"]
}
```

I expect it to connect to the server. The error I'm getting is `[TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "", user "", database "", SSL off`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If anyone has the same issue, I fixed it by adding a field for ssl and setting my ca certificate that I got from Digital Ocean. 
Heres what my ormconfig looks like:

```
module.exports = {
  name: 'default',
  type: 'postgres',
  host: 'host',
  port: port,
  username: 'username',
  password: 'password',
  database: 'database',
  synchronize: true,
  dropSchema: false,
  logging: true,
  ssl: {
    ca: process.env.SSL_CERT,
  },
  entities: ['src/**/*.entity.ts', 'dist/**/*.entity.js'],
};
```

Comment: Hello, I have the same issue. But I don't have any ssl cerificate. Do you any advice or sujestion? or is it mandatory to get a ssl certificate?. Could you helpme with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65136834/what-is-wrong-with-my-posgress-connection-and-my-nestjs-backend-orm    please.

Comment: If you have hosted database you want to connect to you need to download SSL certificate from that platform, you can use that certificate then. it's probably something like `ca_certificate.crt` and you can find more about it in your cloud hosting provider documentation.

Comment: I had a similar issue on Digitalocean. But I was using the url parameter in the typeorm config, and the url from DO contains sslmode=require at the end. It turns out that the sslmode parmeter in the url overwrites the ssl-parameter in config, s o the ca parameter was never set. See: https://node-postgres.com/features/ssl

Comment: But what's actually stored in that SSL_CERT environment variable??

Comment: @Musilix the contents of the .crt file you get from Digital Ocean (or whomever), with the newlines removed so it's all on one line

Comment: For anyone wondering where the certificate and other variables are coming from: only the DATABASE_URL environment variable will be set by default. You have to configure the other ones by yourself, see https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/app-platform/how-to/use-environment-variables/#databases
There is currently an open issue when using the url property. I got it working by not using the url property and by defining each setting (e.g. host, username, ...) separately

Answer (score 35):

This works if you are connecting to postgres database on heroku from localhost using typeorm.

`ormconfig.json`

```
{
  "name": "default",
  "type": "postgres",
  "url": "postgres://username:password@host:port/database",
  "synchronize": true,
  "logging": true,
  "entities": ["src/entity/*.*"],
  "ssl": true,
  "extra": {
    "ssl": {
      "rejectUnauthorized": false
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: on azure, you're going to need the cert as well- https://stackoverflow.com/a/63043606/228369

Answer (score 7):

This is my NestJS TypeORM config on Heroku:

```js
TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
  type: 'postgres',
  url: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  autoLoadEntities: true,
  ssl:
    process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
      ? { rejectUnauthorized: false }
      : false,
}),
```

The SSL option is mandatory as described here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#connecting-in-node-js

Answer (score 2):

```
  ssl: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    ca: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/server-certificates/root.crt').toString(),
    key: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/client-key/postgresql.key').toString(),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/client-certificates/postgresql.crt').toString(),
  },
```

via https://node-postgres.com/features/ssl

Comment: It's not the greatest answer, but this does answer the actual question, the link is correct

Answer (score 2):

Add this line to your config settings:

```
options: { encrypt: false }
```

Your configuration should look something like this:

```
TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
  type: 'mssql',
  host: 'your_db_server_address',
  port: 1433,
  username: 'user',
  password: 'pwd',
  database: 'your_db_name_here',
  entities: [Subscription],
  options: { encrypt: false }
  
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to the above, I spent ages fiddling around with ssl and no-authorize and ca certs, but simply passing env var: PGSSLMODE=no-verify fixed all the issues for me.

Answer (score 1):

With AWS RDS, it sufficed to point TypeORM to AWS's CA bundle:

```js
      ssl: {
        ca: readFileSync(join(__dirname, 'assets', 'RDS.us-east-1.ca-bundle.pem')).toString()
      },
```

on the same level where `url`, `username`, `password`, `logging`... [DataSourceOptions](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/data-source-options) occur.

The CA-bundle PEM file itself was downloaded from https://truststore.pki.rds.amazonaws.com/us-east-1/us-east-1-bundle.pem — and plumbed to distribute with the app's assets.

The CA-certs there are valid until something like 2061, so should be fine to commit into git.

Dig into the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html) for further detail.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `PQSSLMODE` environment variable to `require` - `libpq` will read those automatically, if not set otherwise, and establish a secure connection.

See also: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server and typeorm of `type: "mssql"` I had to add the `extra` field with `trustServerCertificate` as true

```js
import { DataSourceOptions } from 'typeorm';

const config: DataSourceOptions = {
    type: "mssql",
    host: "dev",
    database: "dev",
    username: "",
    password: "",
    synchronize: false,
    logging: false,
    entities: [
        "src/entity/**/*.ts"
    ],
    migrations: [
        "src/migration/**/*.ts"
    ],
    subscribers: [
        "src/subscriber/**/*.ts"
    ],
    extra: {
        trustServerCertificate: true,
    }
};

export default config;
```